# Html code to Hide Ribbon based on user permission in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, master-page, custom-masterpage

I am trying to hide SharePoint ribbon in master page based on permissions. I am using Seattle master page.

After going through many blogs, I tried as below
Wrap ms-designer-ribbon div tag between SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl tag. Just like shown in https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/

But when I add between SPSecurityTrimmedControl tag, the ribbon is completely hidden to everyone. Its not getting hidden based on permissions. I have not even added CSS style as `display:none`.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
 <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly">-->
        <!--SPM:<wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />-->
     <div id="ms-designer-ribbon">
                <!--SID:02 {Ribbon}-->
                <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify) --><div class="DefaultContentBlock" style="background:rgb(0, 114, 198); color:white; width:100%; padding:8px; height:64px; overflow:hidden;">In true previews of your site, the SharePoint ribbon will be here.</div><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW -->
    </div>
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **PermissionsString** in your code.

As per the reference you provided, you can add any permission type from the below list based on your requirement:

- FullMask
- EmptyMask
- ManagePermissions
- ManageSubwebs
- ManageWeb
- AddAndCustomizePages
- BrowseDirectories
- ViewPages
- ManageAlerts

Read more about SharePoint Base Permissions at [SPBasePermissions Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions)

Comment: Hello Ganesh, even after adding permissionstring - FullMask the ribbon is not being displayed. Ribbon is getting hidden all time.

Comment: Hi Usha, does this issue resolved? Have you followed the exact same steps given in article?

Comment: Hello Ganesh, Thank you for followup and sorry that i couldnt update back.  yes the issue has been resolved by adding a separate SPSecurityTrimmedControl . Means now i have the original TrimmedControl as is and wrapped ms-designer-ribbon in another SPSecurityTrimmedControl with ManageWeb PermissionsString. else it wasnt working.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out for you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same issue to find the correct answer easily in future .